# Events - Registrant can view own registration

Tags: civievent

Am I missing something in events to allow a registrant to view their own registration?

This is probably a similar problem to my other issue allowing registrants to update their registrations, but I want to make sure.

Comment: welcome - normally an email is sent to the registrant with their registration data on it - only other option i know of is giving them access to View Contact Dashboard, which shows the events they are registered for, but not the minutae of what price options they booked, or custom fields etc